# update field with special conditions

Tags: sql, sql-update

How to update the password for username (of type Admin) with next condition: first 3 letters of his name, 2 last letters of the last name and 4 last digits of his phone

```sql
create table company 
(
    CODE_COMPANY char(30),
    NAME_COMPANY varchar2(30) not null,
    MAIL_COMPANY varchar2(30) null,

    constraint PK_CODE_COMPANY primary key (CODE_COMPANY),
);

create table USERNAME 
(
    NAME_USERNAME varchar2(30),
    USER_LOCATION number,
    fNAME varchar2 (30) not null,
    lNAME varchar2 (30) not null,
    PHONE_USER char(13) null,
    PASSWORD varchar2(30) not null,
    USER_POSITION varchar2 (30),
    check (USER_POSITION in('Admin', 'Superadmin', 'Technician', 'Student')),

    constraint PK_NAME_USERNAME primary key (NAME_USERNAME),
    constraint FK_USER_LOCATION foreign key (USER_LOCATION) references uLOCATION (LOCATION)
);

create table uLOCATION 
(
    LOCATION number,
    CODE_COMPANY char(30),
    NAME_LOCATION varchar2(30) not null,
    FLOOR_LOCATION varchar2(10),
    check (FLOOR_LOCATION in ('MAIN_FLOOR', '1ST FLOOR', '2ND FLOOR', '3RD FLOOR')),

    constraint PK_LOCATION primary key (LOCATION),
    constraint FK_CODE_COMPANY_L foreign key (CODE_COMPANY) references company (CODE_COMPANY),
);
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: stop using the `char` data type. It has absolutely no advantage whatsoever over `varchar` (or `varchar2`)  but does have some disadvantages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle concat function accepts only two parameters, so there must be two nested concats to join 3 strings together.

```
update username set password = 
concat(
  concat(
  substr(fname,1,3),
  substr(lname, length(lname) - 1)
  ),
  substr(phone_user, length(phone_user) - 3)
)
where user_position = 'Admin';
```

These links explain how substr() works with length()

https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/substr.php

https://www.w3resource.com/oracle/character-functions/oracle-length-function.php

Comment: Look's good, but I got and error : ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments, what means the -1 for lenght of lName?

Comment: I updated the answer to fix that error and explain, let me know how it goes

Comment: another error with LENGHT: ORA-00904: "LENGHT": invalid identifier

Comment: Should be spelled like this 'length'

Comment: OK. That's work perfect. Thx Mark for your time